# Java regex - get specific part of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to access a certain part of multiple strings that follow a pattern.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
String s = "Hello my name is Joe";    
if(Pattern.matches(s,"Hello my name is ([\\w]*)"))
{
    System.out.println("Name entered: $1");
}
```

However, my code never enters inside the "if-statement"

Comment: the `if` line is missing a closing parenthesis...

Comment: Have you actually checked the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swap the parameters to the `matches` method, and your `if` will work (regex is the 1st parameter, not the second).

However, you still won't print the first capturing group with `$1`. To do so:

```
String s = "Hello my name is Joe";    
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Hello my name is ([\\w]*)").matcher(s);
if(m.matches())
{
    System.out.println("Name entered: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: well, that was embarrassing. Thank you. Also, I think the second line should be Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Hello my name is ([\\w]*)").matcher(s);

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for this:

```
final String s = "Hello my name is Joe";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hello my name is (\\w++)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
   System.out.printf("Name entered: %s\n", m.group(1));
}
```

This will capture the `\w++` group value, only if `p` matches the entire content of the String. I've replaced `\w*` with `\w++` to exclude zero length matches and eliminate backtracks.

For further reference take a look at [The Java Tutorial > Essential Classes - Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Matcher class, see this page for more information about Regular Expressions in Java http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the parameters to `Pattern.matches()` backwards.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Also, you don't need a set (the brackets). In addition, You are going to need to use the `Matcher` class and get the brackreference via the `group()` method.