# is there a way I can only parse a part of string?

Tags: java

Say I have this code

```
String age = "My name is John and I am 18 years old";
```

Is there a way to parse only "18" into a integer and leave rest of it as a string?
thanks

Comment: Yes. Look up regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex - get specific part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551747/java-regex-get-specific-part-of-string)

Comment: 1) extract the part of the string you want to parse. 2) parse the string extracted

Comment: Would you like to extract the first occurrence of an integer in a string into a separate int variable?

Comment: What are input strings you expect? Should it also support "Hello, 9 apples please!"? Should it support "I am between 18 and 21 years old"? Please provide elaborate examples, show what you've tried and how that did not work.

Comment: Proper solution depends on (1) how possible input string may look like (2) what should be result for it (include logic/steps which *you* used to get that result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String age = "My name is John and I am 18 years old";

Integer.parseInt(age.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

This will also remove non-digits in-between digits, so "`2k4t1`" becomes `241`.

If you need to confirm that the string consists of a sequence of digits (at least one) possibly followed a letter, then use this:

```
age.matches("\\d+[A-Za-z]?")
```

Comment: `\\D` doesn't need to be in character class `[..]` since it itself is predefined character class.

Comment: I am explicitly mentioning it, it is not issue i guess. Can you elaborate , thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean that `\D` doesn't need to be written as `"[\\D]"` but simply as `"\\D"`. There is no need to surround it with `[` `]` which creates character class, since `\D` already is character class. Each tool should be used according to its purpose and since there is no need for `[` `]` adding it will only cause unnecessary confusion (especially for someone new to regex). EDIT: same applies for `\d` or other predefined character classes like `\w`.

Comment: @Pshemo, ahh i got your point sir, i will keep it in mind, i even learnt it just now that it can cause confusion. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be to use a Scanner to extract the first occurrence of an Integer in a given String:

```
int res = new Scanner("My name is John and I am 18 years old").useDelimiter("\\D+").nextInt();
```

Remember to call the method hasNextInt() before calling nextInt() to make sure it doesn't throw exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
String age = "Mon nom est John et j'ai 18 ans";
age = age.replaceAll("\\D+","");
System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(age));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String age = "My name is John and I am 18 years old";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("My name is John and I am ([\\w]*) years old").matcher(age);
if (matcher.matches()) {
   System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i<age.length; i++){
if (Character.isLetter(age.charAt(i)
s+=age.charAt(i);
}
int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
```